# Can "x'/level" area effects be set at smaller sizes?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, psionics, area-of-effect

For example, a 12th level character produces an effect that has "x'/level" area of effect. Can the character control the size of the area of effect, or not? It would be nice to have a quote of where it is specified for powers (and spells), if possible.

Comment: My apologies, deleted my erroneous comment

Answer (score 14):

> You can cast a spell at a lower caster level than normal, but the caster level you choose must be high enough for you to cast the spell in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same caster level.

<sup>([Magic Overview > Casting Spells > Caster Level](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#casterLevel))</sup>

> You can manifest a power at a lower manifester level than normal, but the manifester level must be high enough for you to manifest the power in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same manifester level.

<sup>([Psionic Powers Overview > Manifester Level](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#manifesterLevel))</sup>

So by default you can reduce the area of the spell or power, but not without also reducing its other level-scaling parameters. Particular abilities (Sculpt Spell/Power metamagic/psionic feats, the archmage’s mastery of shaping high arcana/archpsion’s sculpt power high psionics, etc.) can create exceptions to this, however.

Comment: What about powers? This answer seems one sided, in light of the tags on the question?

Comment: @nijineko The powers tag doesn’t refer specifically to psionic powers—that tag primarily reflects the 4e usage of the term, where it was a catch-all term for an ability of any sort. The psionics tag would more correctly reflect the intent here.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that distinction.

Answer (score 11):

## A typical manifester generally can't opt to have a power affect a littler area

No general rule says that a manifester can change a power's listed area. However, manifesting a power at a lower manifester level can change a power's area if the power's area depends upon the power's manifester level. That is, on [Manifester Level](http://dndsrd.net/psionic.html#manifester-level) says

> You can manifest a power at a lower manifester level than normal, but the manifester level must be high enough for you to manifest the power in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same manifester level. (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 54)

For example, a psion 15 could manifest the 7th-level psion/wilder power [*divert teleport*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersDtoF.html#divert-teleport) [psychoportation] (96) at a manifester level of anywhere from 13 to 15 but not lower than 13, and the power's area would be altered in proportion to the picked manifester level.

### A typical caster suffers a similar restriction on a spell

Likewise, no general rule says that a caster can whimsically change a spell's area. Further, rules nearly identical to those for powers apply to spells (i.e. "You can cast a spell at a lower caster level than normal, but the caster level you choose must be high enough for you to cast the spell in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same caster level" (*Player's Handbook* 171) [here](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#caster-level))).

For example, a Wiz13 could cast the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*control water*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-water) [trans] (214) at any caster level from 11 to 13 but not lower than 11, and the spell's area would be altered in proportion to the picked caster level.

A specific character can devote resources like class levels, feats, and gp (in the form of magic and psionic items) to change a power or spell's area—some examples of which can be found in fine answers [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165110/8610) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165108/8610)—, but changing a spell's area is not an option generally available to all casters or manifesters for free.

Comment: What about powers? This answer seems one sided, in light of the tags on the question?

Answer (score 0):

## YES by reducing your caster level and with the *Sculpt Spell* Metamagic feat but what you can is limited

(**There was no psionic tags when I first answered this question as far as I remember**)

As both [KRyan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165108/51979) and [Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165107/51979)  pointed out you can indeed reduce your caster level to do so and they also covered the psionic/powers part that was not included in the original question [KRyan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165108/51979) **also included more ways to modify your spell area.**

Another way would be to use the *Sculpt Spell* Metamagic feat wich states:

(*Complete Arcane* p.83)

> Benefit
>
> You can modify an area spell by changing the area's shape to either a cylinder (10-foot radius, 30 feet high), a 40-foot cone, four 10-foot cubes, a ball (20-foot-radius spread), or a 120-foot line. The sculpted spell works normally in all respects except for its shape. For example, a lightning bolt whose area is changed to a ball deals the same amount of damage, but affects a 20-foot-radius spread.
>
> A sculpted spell uses a spell slot one level higher than the spell's actual level.

So it is useful to modify the spell area and it could reduce the surface of the spell by increasing it's height instead if you change it to a cylinder for example.

The ''four 10-foot cubes'' is an interesting choice, you can target 4 specific areas (within the spell range limit of course) and [they don't need to be adjacent.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77843/51979)

### Sidenotes:

- It does mention that you modify the **area** of the spell so a spell
  without an area of effect cannot be modified by the feat, *lightning
  bolt* has an area of a 120ft line (given example) so it can be
  modified.
- Spells with area different from the options of *Sculpt spell* such as *control water* could be modified since they have an area but I guess a discussion with the DM would be a good idea.
- [Sculpt Spell has specific boundaries that constrain the spell area](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165141/51979)

Comment: Can someone help for my 3rd  bullet point in my Sidenote? perhaps I should post a new question? can someone name me some spells with an area that goes bigger/caster level please?

Comment: One spell that should work is [*control water*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-water).

Comment: @HeyICanChan thank you, but I don't think it is compatible with sculpt spell though because you don't ''create an area spell'' in this case, you modify water that is already there, so you can't change it's shape, the ''area'' determines what amount of water you can move, and the effect is to low or raise water, of course if there is already a magic cylinder of water or 4 10-foot cubes of water magically suspended somewhere I would allow it to be influenced by the spell that way. Is there other examples of such spells? and one that would fit my need for my answer maybe?

Comment: Well I read the spell again and you can create a whirlpool on the ocean or even When you cast on water elementals!. so I guess it could work with subtle spell via those options! the only point not covered is: **let's say you want to cast Sculpt Control Water to modify the area to 4 10-foot cubes instead will the new shape be bigger depending on your caster level or will it use the fixed size shapes of the sculpt spell feat?**  I'll ask a question

Comment: What about powers? This answer seems one sided, in light of the tags on the question?

Comment: There's also the Archmage class ability, IIRC.

Comment: Oh true indeed I'll check psionics I don't know if they have metamagic too though. Those are new tags! My question is not good now!

Comment: There are metapsionic feats, and an arch psion prestige, as I recall. And yes, there was a "powers" tag from the beginning, which I thought meant psionic powers. I've changed the tag to "psionics" now at KRyan's comment.

Comment: I added the power tag as a suggestion and it got removed ok